# Finding users average purchase rate in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables for purchases and users (will include the schema below). What I want to find out is the average rate of purchase for all users within a timeframe.

To be clear, I don't want (total purchase/total users), I'd like to know more like users make ***"2 purchases every month"***

I couldn't figure out the right algorithm to use although I thought it might be dependent on datediff between purchases. Any help on how to think about this algorithm and the actual code will be welcome

User table:

```
ID        NAME        EMAIL      CREATED
2907      Philip      xxxx       Friday, April 6, 2018 14:55 PM
2859      Jane        xxxx       Friday, April 6, 2018 12:36 PM
```

Purchase table:

```
ID        TIMESTAMP                            SKU       USER_ID
1152497   Tuesday, April 10, 2018 12:05 AM     46        98271
1152498   Tuesday, April 10, 2018 12:05 AM     7887      207120
```

Current code that gets the "user ID, count of purchases and sum purchased"

```
SELECT count(*) AS count, sum(b.price) AS sum, u.id AS id, DATEDIFF(MAX(p.timestamp),MIN(p.timestamp)) as date_diff
FROM purchase p
LEFT JOIN book b on p.book_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN user u on p.user_id = u.id
WHERE date(p.timestamp) BETWEEN date(date_add(now(), INTERVAL -365 day)) AND date(date_add(now(), INTERVAL -1 day))
AND u.timestamp BETWEEN date(date_add(now(), INTERVAL -730 day)) AND date(date_add(now(), INTERVAL -365 day))
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Current Results

```
Count     Sum       ID        Date Diff
634       4,240     88,981    226
549       9,432     130,140   337
387       518,009   113,849   320
```

Comment: So you want 'total purchase'/'total users'/'time period'?  (ie PER a certain time period)

Comment: If you want the actual code you could encourage this by providing sample data and expected output as text in your question

Comment: sounds like maybe a count of purchases grouped by time period (which is probably a derived field which calculates the month of the timestamp) and maybe by user. Once you've got each user's purchase rate per month, you can calculate averages etc based on that

Comment: @ADyson, I think we thought I along the same lines as well. I am posting the current snippet of code in the question. I'm trying to figure out the nested query for getting the date difference

Comment: it would help a lot if you post some sample data, your expected output, and the output your query currently produces. Thanks.

Comment: Made some edits to the code. But I'm worried I might still have the algorithm wrong. At the moment, I'm getting the difference between first purchase and last purchase. The plan is to divide this difference in days by the count of purchases and get an average of that for all users. Would this be a smart way to get frequency of purchase for the entire user base on a 1yr period?